# I get error #include <czmq.h> missing when running program

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, zeromq

I am trying from past 4 days to get Zeromq working on my Windows machine but nothings seems to go my way.

I followed given steps and solved few dependcy issues.

I have build libzmq,czmq,libsodium successfully.

I used cmake 3.12 to configure and VS2015 SDK 8.1 to build solution.

I was able to run czmq_selftest.exe however it failed for few things and thats different issue.

But when I try to run basic program myapp.c

```
#include <czmq.h>
int main (void) {
 zsock_t *publisher = zsock_new (ZMQ_PUB);
 zsock_set_curve_server (publisher, true);
 puts ("Hello, Curve!");
 zsock_destroy(&publisher);
 return 0;
}
```

I see this missing library issue , I tried given link method-

```
 gcc myapp.c -o myapp -lczmq -lzmq
```

But nothing is working it would be really helpful if someone can provide some solution.

Here is other info -

```
OS - Windows 10
Cmake - 3.13.2
Visual Studio 2015, SDK 8.1
libzmq 4.3.0
czmq 4.1.1
```

Source: https://github.com/zeromq/czmq

More information-

My system-

```
C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\include
```

contains all the libraries.

My program is in -

```
C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\examples\security
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the czmq library installed? Where is the libraries header files installed? Do you perhaps need to pass the `-I` (upper-case i) option to specify the location of the header files? And of course, the header file *is* installed somewhere?

Comment: I have added some more info of header files, library files if you mean by "czmq.lib" and "libczmq.dll"  then its stored at "C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug\"

Comment: So, is your question about proper using of CMake or a command line compilation? If you want to ask about CMake approach, show your `CMakeLists.txt` script. Otherwise, remove `cmake` tag as unrelated.

Comment: @Tsyvarev well I put cmake tag as I had used cmake for configure and generate and felt this could be one of the reasons of failure. Well I will update CmakeList if it can be useful here.

Comment: I have remove cmake tag from this question,  I will ask separate question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't keep track of all libraries that a user might have installed on a system by itself. You have to tell the compiler where it can find things like header files or linker-libraries.

To tell the compiler to add a path to the list it uses for searching for header file, use the `-I` (upper-case i) option.

To tell the linker to add a path to the list it uses to search for linker-libraries use the `-L` option.

Considering the paths you mention in your question and comments you need to add both `-I../../include` and `-L../../Debug`.

That is, your complete command should look something like

```
gcc myapp.c -o myapp -I../../include -L../../Debug -lczmq -lzmq
```

Of course, that requires your to be in the directory `C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\examples\security` as you say.

Comment: The above method now gives me strange error-


C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible

Comment: Also just for simplification and understanding the issue, I copied the missing header file in directory which has myapp.c file but its still showing me the same issue.

Comment: @gadhvi For the linker errors, you should probably ask a new question. For the other problem, if you want to include header files from the same directory as the source file itself use double-quotes instead, as in `#include "czmq.h"`

Comment: Well you are right, I need to ask another as this is actually solved.