# Skipping incompatible czmq.lib when searching for -lczmq,

Tags: c, gcc, zeromq

I am trying to get ZeroMQ work on Windows 10 but with no success.
I have compiled the dependent libraries using cmake and Visual Studio and it was successfully built.

However I ran into error when trying the example problem and realized there is a linking error, system is unable to locate the header files stored.

I had asked previously about this issue here which partially solved but I still got error, [I get error #include <czmq.h> missing when running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144527/i-get-error-include-czmq-h-missing-when-running-program?noredirect=1#comment95122612_54144527-)

So I tried manually providing the path to gcc and got some wierd error-
Here is example code which I used

```
    #include <czmq.h>

    int main (void) {
     zsock_t *publisher = zsock_new (ZMQ_PUB);
     zsock_set_curve_server (publisher, true);
     puts ("Hello, Curve!");
     zsock_destroy(&publisher);
     return 0;
    }
```

I compiled the above code using below method-

```
gcc hello.c -o myapp -lczmq -lzmq -I "C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\include" -L "C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug"
```

As earlier I was getting as missing  error and here is the output.

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug/czmq.lib when searching for -lczmq
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug/libczmq.dll when searching for -lczmq
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug/czmq.lib when searching for -lczmq
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug/libczmq.dll when searching for -lczmq
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug\czmq.lib when searching for -lczmq
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lczmq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I am stuck with such simple things which aren't working :(
Any suggestion will really be helpful.

Comment: your title is wrong, it concerns _czmq.lib_, not _#include <czmq.h>_

Comment: _I have compiled the dependent libraries using cmake and Visual Studio_ : cmake used gcc ? Probably the dll was made by Visual Studio

Comment: Ok I will edit the question, Yes I used cmake to configure and generate files and the solution was built using Visual Studio , so I got .dll files using VS2015.

Comment: @gahvi it is worst now, do you understand the difference between a header file and a library file ?

Comment: My bad, I know the difference but I was confused on how to frame the question.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119714/skipping-incompatible-libraries-at-compile), that error means that the library is built for the wrong architecture. Maybe one of them is built for 32-bit, and the other is built for 64 bit. Can you run `file C:\Users\P\go\src\github.com\zeromq\czmq\Debug/czmq.lib` ?

Comment: @NickODell I executed above command using mingw64 -

 `/c/Users/P/go/src/github.com/zeromq/czmq/Debug/czmq.lib: current ar archive`